# Eftpos Hypercom T4220 .net integration

Tags: .net, serial-port, hex, ascii

I am trying to write an application to send information to an Eftpos Hypercom T4220 through serial in .NET.

I have tried in a console test application to use a serial port to send information and to get ANY response at all with no avail -

```
_port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
_port.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(port_ErrorReceived);
_port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_port.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
_port.Open();
_port.Write("test");
```

No messages received on the handler, I have tried sending bytes also, the above configuration for the port came with some documentation for the model.

The documentation also states it needs to send a start code (0x02) then message then end code (0x03).

Has anyone had any luck with these before?

Answer (score 0):

How are you converting the HexString to byte?
you need to do it before _port.Write() Function !!

Comment: The above is just one example of the config I tried, I have used writing a byte array of one, i.e Byte[] b = new Byte[] { 0x02, 0x03 };
_port.write(b,0,b.length);
but still no response.

Answer (score 0):

plus you shall also define the offset and the length of the bytes to send to the serial machine, as most of the machines require these info.

Comment: I agree your point as initial configuration should match for two machines ti communicate.